# How do I declare multiple javascript variables using razor (.net core)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

When declaring two (or more) variables in javascript using @Model I always get an unexpected token syntax error.

```
var a = @Model.Something;
var b = @Model.SomethingElse;
```

I get unexpected token ; if I remove the semi-colon I get unexpected token var. I've tried moving them out of the function, declaring them with commas etc. and still get the same syntax error.

I suppose I must be missing something that should be obvious but I can't figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the model variables in js like below:

```
var a = '@Model.Something';
var b = '@Model.SomethingElse';
```

Comment: Thank you! That was figuratively killing me.